# Sending and Receiving JSON in Python2.4

Tags: python

Typically I use json and the requests module in Python2.7 to query a RESTful API. However I need to do this within Python2.4. 
What is the best method to do this without upgrading ?

Thanks,

Comment: There comes a point when the only reasonable answer is "don't do that". The [last binary release](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.4.4/) of Python 2.4 was in 2006 - it's time to move on, especially if you're planning to transfer anything across an insecure channel like the internet.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus while updating is generally the right thing to do, sometimes that's just not possible. E.g. if you're developing and administering enterprise level software for customers, you can't just go and update stuff on a production server; any update needs to be approved in a lengthy process that costs all involved sides a ton of time and money. Even without these restrictions, it can be impossible - I'm writing a lot of python2.5 because I have to deal with jython; and I wrote an answer for jython2.1 just a week ago because apparently that's still the default for websphere/WAS 8.5.5...

Comment: Copy the required modules from Python2.7 to Python2.4.